# why isn't Object.prototype === to myNewObj.prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

So if you look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r0k3t/z8f2N/1/ you can see that

```
var me = { fName: "ken", lName: "n" };

console.log(Object.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(me));
```

returns true. Why doesn't

```
console.log(Object.prototype === me.prototype);
```

Given that I created the "me" object as an object literal sure enough it's prototype should be Object.prototype and the first line would seem to confirm that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Object.prototype === me.constructor.prototype; // true
```

I let you guess now how `getPrototypeOf` works :-)

Also, the non-standard-yet-but-works-almost-everywhere solution (thanks jAndy):

```
Object.prototype === me.__proto__; // true
```

Comment: +1 - a great addition to your answer would be: `console.log(Object.prototype === me.__proto__);` *(which will get standardized by ES6*

Comment: Oh Darnit! I knew that too (well seen it). I wish I could absorb everything the first time and remember it all.

Comment: Hang on though - why does Yehuda Katz say in his blog  (http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/) under the section "Object Literals" - "object literals always set the newly created object’s prototype to an object located at Object.prototype", then look at the image. Can you blame me for being confused? yeesh!

Comment: Well, internally, browsers use `__proto__`. This is non-standard, but this is the way it works... so yeah. Using the `prototype` property though, the parent's prototype is in `constructor`.